# Highly Available and Customizable Load Balancer (prefer HAProxy) in Oracle Cloud Infrastracture (OCI)

Tags: load-balancing, oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am in need for highly available and customizable Load Balancer instead of needing to use the default Load balancer.

How can i setup HA Proxy based Load Balancer in Oracle Cloud Infrastracture (OCI)

Comment: Could you please share which features do you miss from the built in Load Balancing service?

Answer (score 0):

You should try it using these guides:

- for Oracle Linux 6:
  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/section_jf5_zsb_nr.html
- for Oracle Linux 7:
  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/section_jf5_zsb_nr.html